# Display images on click inside div which is also fadedIn on that click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically i need to display all the images inside `#ImageContainer` inside fixed Div.
Everything works fine except that the when i click one of the images it disapears from the `#ImageContainer`.Like the image moves from `#ImageContainer` to `#BigImage`. Can't find a possible reason for this issue i don't see it normal in my Jquery code.
Also if you can give me a better solution for this purpose feel free to explain it in the comments.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="ImageCotainer">
        <div id="headerLogo">
            <div id="Logo">

            </div>
        </div>
        <img src="images/hotel/1.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="images/hotel/2.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="images/hotel/3.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="images/hotel/4.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="images/hotel/5.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="images/hotel/6.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="images/hotel/7.jpg" alt="">
    </div>

    <div id="BigImage">
        <img src="images/wedding/4.jpg" alt=""> 
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#BigImage{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 700px;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.95);
    z-index: 50;    
    display: none;
}
#BigImage img{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 500px;
    width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(window).load(function() { 
    $("#Logo").click(function () {
        window.location.href = "hotelM.html"
    });

    $("img").click(function () {
        //var img = $(this);
        $("#BigImage").html(this);
        $("#BigImage").fadeIn(1000);

    });

    $("#BigImage").click(function () {
        $("#BigImage").fadeOut(1000);
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/o7n0jbex/)**

Comment: On click of `img` you want it to move to `#BigImage`?

Comment: That's because you are moving your element, instead of creating a new one. Use clone()

Comment: Your click handler is doing it. This is the image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#BigImage").html($(this).clone());
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/o7n0jbex/1/)**

This is normally done by changing image sources rather than tossing entire elements around, though.

Answer (score 3):

> Like the image moves from #ImageContainer to #BigImage

This is exactly what is happening, the reference of 'this' is the actual dom reference, so when you put it in the other elements html, it moves it.

What you want to do is change

```
$("#BigImage").html(this);
```

to

```
$("#BigImage").html($(this).clone());
```